# Excel: countifs on the same range doesn't work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of members with their birthday. I'd like to count the number of members whose birth month falls in July or August. I tried the following COUNTIFS formula but it did not work

```
=COUNTIFS(AH3:AH135,"=7",AH3:AH135,"=8")------ formula(1) gave zero
```

while individual COUNTIFS worked fine

```
=COUNTIFS(AH3:AH135,"=7") gave 13 and 
=COUNTIFS(AH3:AH135,"=8") gave 6
```

I then defined the range AH3:AH135 as month and tried the following formula. It still did not work.

```
=COUNTIF(month,"=7",month,"=8") gave zero
```

I even tried the following formula and it gave 4, not the correct answer

```
=COUNTIFS(AH3:AH135,OR("=7","=8"))------- formula(2)
```

I had to resort to the following formula to get the correct answer

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(AH3:AH135,{"=7","=8"}) gave 19
```

My questions are:

1. Why didn't formula(1) work? The only reason I can think of is that ranges must be unique. Can't have the same range more than once in the formula.
2. Why did formula(2) give 4? I have no clue what it was doing.

Comment: In your first formula try `>=7` and `<=8`.   [Further Reading](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reason the formula 1 didn't work is because the formula is looking for values "7" **AND** "8" (which is 0). That how COUNTIFS formula works. It looks for values that match all the criteria, **not either** of the criteria.
2. And the reason formula 2 gave you for is probably because there are **few errors in the range "AH3:AH135"** because the formula `OR("=7","=8")` results to an error. and if its counting the number of errors in your range.

**Solution:**

The formula that you could use in your case is `=COUNTIF(AH3:AH135,"=7") + COUNTIF(AH3:AH135,"=8")`